# I am doing stratifiedsplit and getting out of bound error, i dont unerstand why

Tags: python, split, scikit-learn

I am trying to do stratified shuffle split and i am new to this

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

data = featureFormat(my_dataset, features_list, sort_keys = True)
labels, features = targetFeatureSplit(data)
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
features = scaler.fit_transform(features)


split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
print len(features), len(labels)
for train_index,test_index in split.split(features, labels):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    features_train,features_test = features_train[train_index],features_test[test_index] 
    labels_train,labels_test = labels_train[train_index],labels_test[test_index]
```

This is the error i am getting

[image]

Even though the limit is upto 143 its showing 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable name.
These lines  :

```
features_train,features_test = features_train[train_index],features_test[test_index] 
labels_train,labels_test = labels_train[train_index],labels_test[test_index]
```

Should be :

```
features_train,features_test = features[train_index],features[test_index] 
labels_train,labels_test = labels[train_index],labels[test_index]
```

You are basically using the variables before they are even declared. You need to do slicing n the original features and labels.